# 401 exception in java code

Tags: apache, tomcat, authentication, java

I am working on drools and my following code

```
import org.drools.RuleBase;
import org.drools.agent.RuleAgent;
import org.drools.definition.type.FactType;

public class MortgageApplicationTest {
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InstantiationException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

        RuleAgent agent = RuleAgent.newRuleAgent("/mortgageapproval.properties");
        RuleBase rb = agent.getRuleBase();

        FactType appType = rb.getFactType("mortgages.LoanApplication");
        FactType incomeType = rb.getFactType("mortgages.IncomeSource");

        Object application = appType.newInstance();
        Object income = incomeType.newInstance();

        appType.set(application, "amount", 25000);
        appType.set(application, "deposit", 1500);
        appType.set(application, "lengthYears", 20);

        incomeType.set(income, "type", "Job");
        incomeType.set(income, "amount", 65000);


        rb.newStatelessSession().execute(new Object[] {application, income});

        System.out.println(application);
    }

}
```

Following is my mortgageapproval.properties file

```
url=http://localhost:8080/drools-guvnor/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/mortgages/LATEST
userName=admin
password=admin
```

This whole code setup Is throwing following 401 error

```
RuleAgent(default) INFO (Tue Apr 26 11:03:25 IST 2011): Configuring with newInstance=true, secondsToRefresh=-1
RuleAgent(default) INFO (Tue Apr 26 11:03:25 IST 2011): Configuring package provider : URLScanner monitoring URLs:  http://localhost:8080/drools-guvnor/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/mortgages/LATEST
RuleAgent(default) EXCEPTION (Tue Apr 26 11:03:25 IST 2011): Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8080/drools-guvnor/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/mortgages/LATEST. Stack trace should follow.
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8080/drools-guvnor/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/mortgages/LATEST
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1403)
    at org.drools.agent.HttpClientImpl.fetchPackage(HttpClientImpl.java:50)
    at org.drools.agent.URLScanner.readPackage(URLScanner.java:148)
    at org.drools.agent.URLScanner.getChangeSet(URLScanner.java:120)
    at org.drools.agent.URLScanner.loadPackageChanges(URLScanner.java:96)
    at org.drools.agent.RuleAgent.checkForChanges(RuleAgent.java:410)
    at org.drools.agent.RuleAgent.refreshRuleBase(RuleAgent.java:362)
    at org.drools.agent.RuleAgent.configure(RuleAgent.java:347)
    at org.drools.agent.RuleAgent.init(RuleAgent.java:247)
    at org.drools.agent.RuleAgent.newRuleAgent(RuleAgent.java:187)
    at org.drools.agent.RuleAgent.newRuleAgent(RuleAgent.java:147)
    at org.drools.agent.RuleAgent.newRuleAgent(RuleAgent.java:256)
    at com.notidiots.MortgageApplicationTest.main(MortgageApplicationTest.java:19)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

.... I have given authentication only at tomcat's component.xml file which is as follows

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui"/>

<role rolename="admin"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin"/>
```

In my drools' component.xml following line shows I have not given any authentication

```
<!-- NO authentication. This will bypass the login screen when you hit the app. Everyone is "guest" -->

<security:identity authenticate-method="#{nilAuthenticator.authenticate}"/>
```

Please help me out since there are not many drools developer are there... I am not getting required help....

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a 404 error in response when it's trying to fetch the file that you've configured in the `url` setting: `http://localhost:8080/drools-guvnor/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/mortgages/LATEST`

Do the mortgages package and the specific file you're pointing to exist?

Comment: @Shane Madden sorry it was my mistake i posted wrong error message..I corrected it..

Comment: That changes things!  How do your `login-config` and `security-constraint` blocks look in the web.xml (or wherever they're defined)?