# BRMS- resource and change-set

Tags: java, rules, drools, changeset

I am trying to run a Drools project with all the rules created inside the JBRMS. I am having a 401 exception and leading to null point.

```
    package pop.blah.test;

import org.drools.KnowledgeBase;
import org.drools.agent.KnowledgeAgent;
import org.drools.agent.KnowledgeAgentFactory;
import org.drools.io.ResourceFactory;
import org.drools.runtime.StatefulKnowledgeSession;
import org.drools.definition.type.FactType;

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class CarApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        KnowledgeAgent kagent = KnowledgeAgentFactory.newKnowledgeAgent( "MyAgent5" );
        kagent.applyChangeSet( ResourceFactory.newUrlResource("http://localhost:8080/jboss-brms/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/pop.blah.test/CAR"));
        KnowledgeBase kbase = kagent.getKnowledgeBase();
        StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
        ResourceFactory.getResourceChangeScannerService().start();
        try {
        FactType carType = kbase.getFactType( "pop.blah.test", "Car" );
        Object bmw = carType.newInstance();
        carType.set( bmw,"name","My Car" );
        carType.set( bmw,"make","BMW" );
        carType.set( bmw,"year", 1977);
        ksession.insert( bmw );
        ksession.fireAllRules();
        boolean dest = (Boolean) carType.get( bmw, "destroy" );
        if (dest==true) {
            System.out.println("I am gona destroy that car!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("I am happy with my car!");
        }
        } 
        catch (Exception E) {
         E.printStackTrace();   
        }
        finally {
         ksession.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

This is the ERROR I am getting.

```
[2011:12:363 14:12:718:debug] KnowledgeAgent building resource map
[2011:12:363 14:12:718:info] KnowledegAgent has started listening for ChangeSet notifications
[2011:12:363 14:12:718:info] KnowledgeAgent created, with configuration:
monitorChangeSetEvents=true scanResources=true scanDirectories=true newInstance=true
[2011:12:363 14:12:765:exception]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to parse ChangeSet
    at org.drools.agent.impl.KnowledgeAgentImpl.getChangeSet(KnowledgeAgentImpl.java:393)
    at org.drools.agent.impl.KnowledgeAgentImpl.applyChangeSet(KnowledgeAgentImpl.java:168)
    at pop.blah.test.CarApp.main(CarApp.java:16)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8080/jboss-brms/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/pop.blah.test/LATEST
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.drools.io.impl.UrlResource.grabStream(UrlResource.java:210)
    at org.drools.io.impl.UrlResource.getInputStream(UrlResource.java:146)
    at org.drools.io.impl.UrlResource.getReader(UrlResource.java:214)
    at org.drools.agent.impl.KnowledgeAgentImpl.getChangeSet(KnowledgeAgentImpl.java:391)
    ... 2 more
[2011:12:363 14:12:765:exception]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to parse ChangeSet
    at org.drools.agent.impl.KnowledgeAgentImpl.getChangeSet(KnowledgeAgentImpl.java:397)
    at org.drools.agent.impl.KnowledgeAgentImpl.applyChangeSet(KnowledgeAgentImpl.java:168)
    at pop.blah.test.CarApp.main(CarApp.java:16)
[2011:12:363 14:12:765:info] KnowledgeAgent applying ChangeSet
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.drools.agent.impl.KnowledgeAgentImpl.processChangeSet(KnowledgeAgentImpl.java:215)
    at org.drools.agent.impl.KnowledgeAgentImpl.applyChangeSet(KnowledgeAgentImpl.java:183)
    at org.drools.agent.impl.KnowledgeAgentImpl.applyChangeSet(KnowledgeAgentImpl.java:168)
    at pop.blah.test.CarApp.main(CarApp.java:16)
```

---

I am getting a 401 exception. Do I need to include property file for authentication with this for that uri?
My resource has a declarative model and a rule. A simple rule saying that if "year" of car is less than 1989, set the value of "destroy" to true. 
I am going wrong somewhere. Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to guvnor, what kind of resources points to this URL? http://localhost:8080/jboss-brms/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/org.pci/EPOCH? 
Where did you get that URL? do you get a package called org.pci with a resource called EPOCH?
Cheers

Comment: I had edited the code above. URL points to the resources in the BRMS. I created a snapshot and got the URL from there. 401 is an authentication error so does that mean I have to include property file? If yes, where in the Drools project should I place it?

Comment: Just now I added the property file as per this posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791025/401-exception-in-java-code?answertab=oldest#tab-top     Now I am not getting 401 exception but instead an error at the line--- Object bmw = carType.newInstance();

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are including the Car declared type inside the knowledge package?

Comment: As per the documentation I was using the exact code. I think its still authentication problem because the instance of Car cannot be created. The knowledge base is not able to point to the resource. Could you give me some kind of code which can access the resource in the BRMS?